# .NET Core how to override/extend IdentityUserRole and IdentityUserClaim

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to replace the default IdentityUserRole class with my own called UserRoles. What I have done so far:

```
[Table("IdentityUserRole", Schema = "ManagementStudio")]
public class UserRoles : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Users")]
    public override string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUsers Users { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Roles")]
    public override string RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Roles Roles { get; set; }
}
```

In my DbContext class:

```
public DbSet<UserRoles> UserRoles{ get; set; }
```

In my onModelBuilding

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserRoles>()
            .ToTable("IdentityUserRole", schema: "ManagementStudio");
```

This is the error I get when I try to login:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: Cannot create a DbSet for
>   'IdentityUserRole' because this type is not included in the
>   model for the context.
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet.get_EntityType()

This happens for IdentityUserClaim as well.

Comment: Hint: You do not have to use [Table] if you are using entitiy.ToTable already.

Comment: I did that because when I reference this dll, the other application can’t seem to detect its schema

Answer (score 2):

if you look into the definition of IdentityUserRole, you’ll find out that it already has primary keys

```
public class IdentityUserRole<TKey> where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
    public IdentityUserRole();

    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets the primary key of the user that is linked to a role.
    public virtual TKey UserId { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets the primary key of the role that is linked to the user.
    public virtual TKey RoleId { get; set; }
}
```

> we have to override the user role implementation. Now if you see the code, you’ll see that we can override it. So I did this:

```
 public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<
    User,
    Role,
    string,
    IdentityUserClaim<string>,
    UserRole,
    IdentityUserLogin<string>,
    IdentityRoleClaim<string>,
    IdentityUserToken<string>>
```

//And this is to override primary keys in UserRole:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>(userRole =>
    {
        userRole.HasKey(pr => new
        {
            pr.UserId,
            pr.RoleId,
            pr.ClientId
        });
    }
}
```

> After we override the database context, we can use custom TUserRole,
>   for example like this one:

```
   public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    [Required, StringLength(36)]
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. However, I'm getting this error when I perform migrations: The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.AspNetRoles' and the index name 'RoleNameIndex'. The duplicate key value is (SYSTEMADMINISTRATOR).
The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the new model UserRole when inheriting IdentityDbContext on your DbContext class.

Like this.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, Guid, IdentityUserClaim<Guid>, UserRole , IdentityUserLogin<Guid>, IdentityRoleClaim<Guid>, IdentityUserToken<Guid>>
{
    ...
}
```

as you can see, I replaced IdentityUserRole with UserRole since I want to override it.